# Parallel testing on two devices which require different adb version

Tags: android, adb, appium, appium-android

My phone: Kiano elegance 4.0 requires `adb 1.0.36` to use [Appium](http://appium.io/). My [Memu](https://www.memuplay.com/) emulator requires `adb 1.0.31` version to work. Is there any way to use appium on phone and emulator parallel?

Comment: How do you start the appium server?

Comment: @pr4bh4sh from console, but I am also using appium-dotnet-driver.

Comment: Download the both adb version start one appium server on a different terminal window
`export ANDROID_HOME=<path_of_the_adb_36> && appium -p 4723 <other appium param if you have any>`

and second with 
`export ANDROID_HOME=<path_of_the_adb_31> &&  appium -p 4744 <other appium param if you have any>`

And pass the respective appium port number to the driver and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant do that. Yes, you can install different versions of ADB, but you need to set local variable of ANDROID_HOME (which is 1 version only).

Comment: But how can I force appium to use different `ANDROID_HOME` variable?

Comment: like i said before, in my opinion you cant do that. Appium using ANDROID_HOME variable as one and only to work with SDK, i dont think that it is possible to let appium choose another path for sdk